# How to determine whether a separate status bar exists in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, statusbar

My app has an option for going to fullscreen mode, i.e. hiding the status bar via

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

However, on Honeycomb tabs the status bar is combined with the bar that has the softkeys (home, back, ...) and can thus not be hidden. To avoid confusion, I would like to hide the fullscreen option on these devices. I could not find how to determine whether the device I am running on has a separate status bar or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [post](http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/is-displayed-navigationbar.html) will help. There is a hidden API method in the IWindowManager class called `canStatusBarHide` and one called `hasNavigationBar` both of which return booleans and have names that are pretty self-explanatory. You'll need to use Reflection to access them asd they are not available in the SDK.